# PowerShell 5.1 splatting help when parameter is a value of hashtable

Tags: powershell

The following works, however is there a way to make one-liner?

```
$ht = @{}
$ht.add('test1',@{firstname='joh';lastname='smi'})

# make following one-liner
$ht2 = $ht['test1']
Function1 @ht2
```

Comment: if you mean something like `Function1 @ht['splatting_hashtable']` then the answer is no, it will be a parsing error

Comment: does `Function1 $ht['test1']` not work for you?

Comment: Use a semicolon :)  `$ht2 = $ht['test1']; Function1 @ht2`

Comment: Make what a one-liner? A true one-liner is a code that is passed from one side of a pipe to the other. You can't do that with what you have. As '@Daniel' stated. You certainly can put it all on one line, with the semi-colon, but that is not a one-liner. That is just all your code on one line terminated for execution. Btw, doing this sort of thing just makes your code hard to read, maintain and troubleshoot. You could try this ```Function1 @($ht['test1'])``` . Yet, ditto to what '@ Santiago Squarzon' said.

Comment: @postanote that wouldn't be splatting just passing an array as argument, not what OP wanted. What OP wants simply cannot be done in one statement except putting 2 statements in one line with a `;` as Daniel noted